# git tag 'malformed object name' — Github Action/Workflow Subprocess Error

Tags: python, git, github, subprocess, github-actions

I have a Python script that utilizes Subprocess to execute a git command:

```py
import subprocess

fetch_cmd = ['git', 'fetch', '--tags']   //fetch tags 
subprocess.run(fetch_cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)

test_tag = ['git', 'tag', '--points-at', 'origin/test~1']   //acquire tag for a commit in remote test branch
subprocess.run(test_tag, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

I then have a Github workflow/action which runs this Python script. I've had the action run this code successfully in a test env and everything work as expected, so I know a Github action can do this, and this line of code also works in my local terminal. However, after I merge to prod, the Github action fails out trying to run the `git tag` command with the following error:

```
error: malformed object name 'origin/test~1'
    subprocess.run(test_tag, capture_output=True, text=True)
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'tag', '--points-at', 'origin/test~1']' returned non-zero exit status 129.
```

My question is why is this occurring? I'm thinking the Github action environment for test doesn't know where origin is? Is there a command I need Subprocess to run or set beforehand in this environment for 'git' command to be able to access origin?

I'm lost and would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Given that the output generated is visible, consider displaying the output of `git remote -v` and/r `git branch -a` (by running them like you already have) and see whether the target `origin/test~1` actually exists and whether `origin` is a valid remote.

Comment: `//` doesn't denote a comment in python, just a heads up

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question. Looks like an issue with your checkout step. Most probably, you're using the default configuration to checkout i.e. `fetch-depth: 1`. To fetch the complete git history, you should be using `fetch-depth: 0`. See `actions/checkout`'s [usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

@Azeem was exactly right, this was a git issue. In my case the issue stemmed from the workflow and what git within the workflow was able to access. I needed two changes:

1. In my action, updated `actions/checkout` to increase the fetch depth. This essentially enables the workflow's git to be able to "see" all repo branches and not just the one the workflow is running on like it does by default:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: my-action
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      ...
```

2. Explicitly fetching the branch I want to access. Since this was being done in a workflow, I created a step to run this, but the git command here is really what's doing the work:

```
...
- name: Access test branch
    run: git fetch origin test:test --update-head-ok
...
```

After adding these, I was able to access any branch within the repo and not get the error anymore!